# Should I check with 'Get' before make changes to azure resources in powershell

Tags: azure, powershell

I need to add managed identity from script and I'm wondering if this is enought:

```
$webApp = Set-AzWebApp -AssignIdentity $true -Name $webappname -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName
```

Or should I add code to do like this:

```
$webApp = Get-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $webappname

if ($null -eq $webApp.Identity) {
    $webApp = Set-AzWebApp -AssignIdentity $true -Name $webappname -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName 
}
```

What would be better? I'm wondering if `Get-AzWebApp` is smart enough to decide to not to run if there are no changes, or is it just 'deploy new version no matter what'

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to add managed identity, the first command is better. `Set-AzWebApp` will modify and overwrite the Identity of your web app. There is no need to `Get-AzWebApp` to make sure the Identity is null. If the Identity is not null, `-AssignIdentity $true` will overwrite the property.

```
Set-AzWebApp -AssignIdentity $true -Name $webappname -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName
```